# reqFundamentalData IBKR

Tags: interactive-brokers

It seems that the TWS API request `reqFundamentalData` is no longer working. I'm using TWS version 10.19.2. It appears that the server is functioning, but the response is empty; I'm not getting any feedback.

```
# Initializing
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    # Error handling function
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)
        if errorCode == 504:  # Not connected error
            print("Attempting to reconnect...")
            self.reconnect()

    # Inherit and overwrite fundamentalData() function in EWrapper
    def fundamentalData(self, reqId: int, data: str):
        super().fundamentalData(reqId, data)
        self.fundamental_data = data  # Store fundamental data in instance variable
        print("FundamentalData Returned. ReqId: {}, Symbol: {},  XML Data: {}".format(
        reqId, self.contract.symbol, data))
        self.display_fundamental_data()  # Call function to display fundamental data

    def display_fundamental_data(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'fundamental_data'):
             print("Fundamental Data:", self.fundamental_data)
        else:
            print("No fundamental data available.")

    def reconnect(self):
        self.disconnect()
        t.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds before reconnecting (renamed to t)
        self.connect("127.0.0.1", port=7497, clientId=990)

tws = IBapi()                       
tws.connect("127.0.0.1", port=7497, clientId=990)
t.sleep(5)  # Renamed to t
print("Connected to IB server.")

c = Contract()
c.symbol = 'AAPL'  # Changed to c.symbol
c.secType = 'STK'  # Changed to c.secType
c.exchange = "SMART"  # Changed to c.exchange
c.currency = "USD"  # Changed to c.currency

tws.reqFundamentalData(1, c, 'ReportsFinStatements', [])
print("Requested fundamental data for symbol AAPL.")
t.sleep(10)  # Renamed to t
# Implement other requests

tws.disconnect()
print("Disconnected from IB server.")
```

Here is the result.

> Connected to IB server.
> Requested fundamental data for symbol AAPL.
> Disconnected from IB server.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the code looked ok but it didn't run.  I reorganized it a bit and realized you just forgot to call run().

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
import time as t

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString, reject):
        print("error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        c = Contract()
        c.symbol = 'AAPL'  # Changed to c.symbol
        c.secType = 'STK'  # Changed to c.secType
        c.exchange = "SMART"  # Changed to c.exchange
        c.currency = "USD"  # Changed to c.currency
        self.contract = c
        self.reqFundamentalData(1, c, 'ReportsFinStatements', [])
        print("Requested fundamental data for symbol AAPL.")
        
    # Inherit and overwrite fundamentalData() function in EWrapper
    def fundamentalData(self, reqId: int, data: str):
        super().fundamentalData(reqId, data)
        self.fundamental_data = data  # Store fundamental data in instance variable
        print("FundamentalData Returned. ReqId: {}, Symbol: {},  XML Data: {}".format(
        reqId, self.contract.symbol, data))
        self.display_fundamental_data()  # Call function to display fundamental data
        self.disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from IB server.")
        
    def display_fundamental_data(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'fundamental_data'):
             print("Fundamental Data:", self.fundamental_data)
        else:
            print("No fundamental data available.")

tws = IBapi()                       
tws.connect("127.0.0.1", port=7497, clientId=990)
tws.run() # pretty sure you just forgot this line
```